# Jenkins - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, jenkins

I am constantly getting OutofMemory Error. Any idea how to resolve this? Jenkins current version 2.361. Jenkins server have 4 CPU @ 2.40GHZ. RAM 16 GB

Entry in jenkins.xml for heap size is as below.

```
<arguments>-Dpermissive-script-security.enabled=no_security -Xss16m -Xms1024m -Xmx6144m 


Jenkins is configured for JDK 11 from IBM Semeru (see below).
IMPLEMENTOR="International Business Machines Corporation"
IMPLEMENTOR_VERSION="11.0.14.1"
JAVA_VERSION="11.0.14.1"
JAVA_VERSION_DATE="2022-02-08"


Error message on jobs 

    Started by timer
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.base/java.lang.StackWalker.getImpl(Native Method)
```

Comment: This makes me wonder what job you're running which is consuming ~6gb of space, and perhaps that the issue resides there (and not with jenkins)

Comment: what is your job doing?

Comment: Jobs are just running a batch file, python scripts etc. Around 20 jobs in a day